# v-tab-item with prop :touchless="true" still allows user to swipe between tabs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, transition, vuetify-tabs

Steps to reproduce
Add tabs component to page
Use property :touchless="true" on v-tab-item
Swiping with finger still causes transition

Touchless prop should prevent user from swiping.

But I am still able to.

Comment: To allow the community to assist you better, please provide the code you have written.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `touchless` in `v-tabs-items` vuetify tag.

```
<v-tabs-items touchless>
      <v-tab-item>
        //
      </v-tab-item>
      <v-tab-item>
        //
      </v-tab-item>
</v-tabs-items>
```

Answer (score 0):

The touchless tag never worked for me, the solution in my case was to overwrite the :touch directive like this:

```
<v-tab-items>
    <v-tab-item :touch="false">
    </v-tab-item>
</v-tab-items>
```

Comment: There seems to be an issue when the `v-tab-item` is not nested in `v-tab-items` https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/discussions/15336?sort=top, here is an article on using v-tabs with disabled swiping https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1558/how-to-disable-swiping-on-vuetify-tabs

Comment: The `v-tab-item` elements were of course nested in `v-tab-items`. Sorry for the confusion, I corrected my answer.